# iTerm 2 profiles

Tags: macos, iterm

I have recently switched over to iTerm2 and love it. I am wondering though if there is a way to use profiles to correspond to what environment/specific machine you are on.

Say if I am doing tasks in one window on my mac the profile is displayed as default, but if I ssh into a machine (lets say dev0), the profile on iTerm will update to profile dev0. Once I've finished with dev0 and call exit, the profile will switch to default again.

I realize one work around is to open up a specific profile whenever I want to ssh into another machine and have a way to distinguish, but if the connection is closed it requires you to notice based off text rather than say the background of the window.

Is this possible? If not how can this feature be added, and is there a way I can contribute?

Comment: It is a good question, but I am not really sure if this belongs on Stackoverflow.

Comment: you're right I just joined the community, is there a way to move this to SuperUser?

Comment: There is at least one question on SuperUser that references this question in the comments :) http://superuser.com/questions/1052305/mac-osx-terminal-change-background-color-on-login-to-different-server?noredirect=1#comment1475057_1052305

Answer (score 59, accepted):

iTerm2 supports a custom escape code that changes the profile on the fly. Put it in your .bashrc or .bash_profile.

```
<esc>]50;SetProfile=X^G
```

where X is the profile. For instance, to change the profile to one called "Foo", us this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=Foo\a"
```

To change it back when you log out, put code to change the profile back to default in ~/.bash_logout.

Comment: Just an issue with this for anyone else who reads this: if you end up nesting your ssh sessions, you will have to re-source (. ~/.bashrc) after logging out of the second ssh into your first. I normally wouldn't do this but have to if I am working remotely.

Comment: Is it possible to set default profile like this? I tried `SetDefaultProfile`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Just found this list of escape codes, interestingly - SetProfile isn't listed..   I wonder what else is hidden away in there..   http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/documentation/escape_codes

Comment: Just adding to this, I found the following snippet useful for changing profile based on whether I'm ssh'd to a host or not:

`sshToMyFavouriteHost() {
        echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=Profile2\a";
        ssh my.favourite.host.com && echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=Profile1\a"
}`

Comment: Apparently `SetProfile=\a` gives me the default profile back.

Comment: CAUTION: This will prevent you from accessing your server by SFTP.

Comment: The post below this by @Yohaï Berreby worked for me and is a good resource if you wish to do this strictly through the UI

Comment: The `50` is now `1337` because of conflicts with xterm. The command is now `<esc>]1337;SetProfile=NewProfileName^G` as [described here.](http://www.iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html)

Comment: @scubbo: You may already have discovered this, but there is explicit support for automatic [host-, user-, and location-triggered profile switching.](http://www.iterm2.com/documentation-automatic-profile-switching.html)

Answer (score 16):

**for zsh users**

lets say you have 2 profiles, one named **mac** (for your primary machine) and one for **linux** (your remote machine)

**when entering the session**, we need to tell zsh to load our profile

1. connect to remote linux
2. in `~/.zshrc` add `echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=linux\a"`
3. source your files for immediate effect: `source ~/.zshrc`
4. your new theme should be visible within the iterm session.

**when exiting the session**, we need to tell zsh to switch back to our original profile

1. connect to remote linux
2. in linux `~/.zlogout` add the following

```
if [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
  echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=mac\a"
  clear
fi
```

now you can swap profiles with ease <3.

if you are using bash, i believe the steps are similar but you would instead modify `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_logout`

**demo**

[image: demo of session based profiles in iterm2]

Comment: I gave this a thumbs-up specifically for the ~/.bash_logout information.

Comment: Hello, does this still work with version 3.4.12 of iTerm? I can't manage to get it to work although I know it worked before. I can't figure out when it stopped working.

Comment: what shells are you using both local and remote? `echo $0`

Answer (score 14):

The latest iTerm2 nightly (Build 2.9.20150329-nightly at the time of writing) allows you to do that easily. You can download it [here](https://iterm2.com/downloads/nightly/).

Once you've installed and opened it:

1. Log in to your remote machine via ssh and click **iTerm2** (the app menu) > **Install Shell Integration**. It will download a script with `curl` and install it. **Do the same on your local machine**.
2. Go to **Preferences** > **Profiles**.
3. Create a new profile for your local machine. Customize it to fit your needs (change background color, name, etc)
4. Go to the **Advanced** tab and scroll to the bottom.
5. In **Automatic Profile Switching**, click '+' and add the hostname of your local machine. The hostname is the one you get when running `echo $HOST` on the target machine. **It is not always the one you see in your prompt.**
6. Create another profile, this time for your remote machine, and customize it.
7. Add the hostname of the remote machine in **Automatic Profile Switching**.
8. Now, if you ssh into the remote machine, your profile will change, and if you `exit` out of the ssh session, you will be back to your local profile.

You can combine this solution with [@esod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15744584/2754323) seamlessly.
Note: it didn't work for me until I created a profile specifically for the desktop instead of using the default profile.

See [the documentation](http://iterm2.com/automatic-profile-switching.html) for more info.

Comment: Excellent, very concise answer.  As my computer is a work computer, under the ~Automatic Profile Switching~ option, I chose to use @myusername vs. the host name because `echo $HOST was blank`, it was a work computer, and I didn't want to edit my host name.

Answer (score 5):

step 1:

custom your iterm profile, e.g. `dark`, `light`

step 2:

add code before to your shell profile, e.g `.bashrc or .zshrc`

```
# Change iterm2 profile. Usage it2prof ProfileName (case sensitive)
it2prof() { echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=$1\a" }
```

step 3:

make sense your profile

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

step 4:

toggle your iterm theme profile

```
it2prof dark
it2prof light
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same wish and found this can be accomplished in iTerm 2 (Build 1.0.0.20130319) in the application's preferences.

You can assign a profile (say a remote profile) with a different preset than your default preset by going to:

Profiles -> Open Profiles
select the profile and click Edit Profiles...
Go to the Colors Tab and choose a preset for this profile from the list in Load Presets...

Further, I've set up Keys shortcut for different profiles so I can have one iTerm window look different than another window. I did this by:

1. Creating a new a Profile in Preferences
2. Creating a new Profile Shortcut Key in Preferences-> Keys whose action is New Window with Profile

My Default profile has a black background but sometimes it helps me to have a white background. I duplicate my Default profile and name the new profile DefaultLight. On my Default profile I go to the Keys tab where I create a new Profile Shortcut Key whose Keyboard Shortcut is ^+cmd+n, whose action is New Window with Profile, and whose Profile is DefaultLight.

After saving the prefrences, cmd+n opens a new window with a black background and ^+cmd+n opens a new window with a white background.

There's also a New Tab with Profile action in the Keyboard Shortcut Keys Preference if you're interested in taking this even further.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to combine [Yohaï Berreby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29328685/1714013) with my hosts' setting to implement this feature.

> 5. In Automatic Profile Switching, click '+' and add the hostname of your local machine. The hostname is the one you get when running echo $HOST on the target machine. It is not always the one you see in your prompt.

My staging server doesn't set $HOST and host name is :

```
[devel@alveo-staging ~]$ hostname
alveo-staging
```

But I can't set the rule with hostname as `alveo-staging`. Because in fact *alveo-staging* is just an alias of the real hostname (alveo-staging.xxx), which can be set in `/etc/hosts`.

So the quick solution to this is to use * wildcards, to set the rule as `*staging*`.

Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

For **Fishell** user:
1. Create a **fish** function:

`functions it2prof > ~/.config/fish/functions/it2prof.fish`

2. Add this content to `~/.config/fish/functions/it2prof.fish` file and save:

```
function it2prof
  echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=$argv\a"
end
```

3. enjoy your command:

`it2prof whatever_profile_you_define`